# ProgressDialog in AsyncTask not updating or dismissing

Tags: android, dialog, progress, dismiss

I am using an AsyncTask to handle complex background operations (compiling a log file to send) and I use a ProgressDialog to show the user progress. I have tried using showDialog() but it never seems to show or dismiss (it is never called), and I followed tutorials on how to do it... 
So I am using unmanaged ones, and it won't dismiss my message. I am also wanting to update the message as it starts to compile the log file (as it seems to lag there - or maybe the text view is just really long so it doesn't update like it is supposed to).

I have moved my code around a bit so it look like there are problems (like onProgressUpdate()), but I don't know how to make it work. I have looked around this site and nothing seems to be having the problem I am (not exactly anyways). RunOnUiThread() doesn't work, new Thread(){} doesn't work, and onProgressUpdate() I can't get to work (the documentation is confusing on this).

It also never dismisses. I have set up a listener and it never dismisses.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code? I thought AsyncTask was supposed to be simple.

```
        private class BuildLogTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String temp;
        ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(context); //variable is defined at onCreate (held as private, not static)

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            temp = buildLog();
            logdata = temp;
            publishProgress();
            createLogFile();
            return temp;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate() {
            progressdialog.setMessage("Compiling Log File...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.w(TAG,"Showing Dialog");
            send.setEnabled(false);
            ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressdialog.setMessage("Gathering Data...");
            progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressdialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Progress Dialog dismissal.");

                }
            });
            progressdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(){
            Log.e(TAG,"Progress Dialog was Cancelled");
            progressdialog.dismiss();
            logdata=null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressdialog.dismiss();
            send.setEnabled(true);
            previewAndSend();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different progress dialogs there, one local to onPreExecute() and one global. The one ur dismissing in your onPostExecution() is your global one which was never actually shown. Remove the local declaration and it should work.

Comment: Yep... that was it.
I feel dumb now! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. The signature for on onProgressUpdate is not correct.  Try this instead:

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
       progressdialog.setMessage("Compiling Log File...");
   }
2. You're masking the progressDialog member variable with a local variable in onPreExecute()

EDIT: Second problem identified:

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work (like all the other methods I tried). The progress dialog's message just will not update, and it also will not dismiss itself.

Comment: Hmm... that's strange.  Have you tried changing the Progress parameter type from Void to Integer (as detailed in my edit above?)

Comment: Never mind, I see your problem.  You're masking the `progressDialog` member variable with a local variable in `onPreExecute()`

Comment: William found it. I was instantiating another one... I think I had a copy paste problem. (In onPreExecute())

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

Replace:

```
progressdialog.show();
```

For:

```
progressdialog = progressdialog.show();
```

Good luck.